# Pasar variable de un documento .py a otra otro documento .py y al cerrar el documento segundo envie el valor de la variable

Tags: python-3.x

Soy nuevo en python.
La necesidad es muy simple. Tengo una venta principal con dos botones,uno de "Ver" y otro de "Ir".
Si pulso el boton "Ver" imprime el valor de una variable (la cual al empezar tiene el valor de 5).
Si pulso el boton "Ir" debe de cerrar la ventana principal y abrir la segunda ventana (domuento .py diferente).

La segund ventana tiene un boton "Volver", la cual al motrarse cambia el valor de la variable que ha pasado la ventana principal. Cambiando su valor a 10.
Al pulsar en boton de "Volver" se cierra la ventana y pasa la variable a la ventana principal, la cual si pulsa de nuevo el boton de ver escribira 10.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.